# Yii - How to show data based on its Id?

Tags: php, yii

I have menu like this on layouts/main.php:

```
array('label'=>'Data Loket', 'url'=>array('/loket/view', 'id' => Yii::app()->loket->id), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->getLevel()==3),
```

I want to show the list 'loket'  based on its Id. So I  add `'id' => Yii:app()->loket->id`, but it throws error Property "CWebApplication.loket" is not defined.

How to fix this error? Help me please, I just a newbie. Thanks

Comment: have you code any thing for loket?

Comment: I put <?php $loket = Loket::model()->findByAttributes(array('id_nomer' => $this->id_nomer)) ?> in main.php

Answer (score 0):

Get the results using the following code:

```
$loket      = Loket::model()->findByAttributes(array('id_nomer' => $this->id_nomer));
$loket_data = $loket->attributes;
$loket_id   = $locket_data['id']
```

You can shorten this, but I broke it up into 2 steps to show the progression.

Comment: I have tried but it throws another error Property "CWebApplication.id_nomor" is not defined. I have put `$loket      = Loket::model()->findByAttributes(array('id_nomer' => $this->id_nomer));` in SiteContoller.php but still error

Comment: As you haven't given us the full code, I cannot help further. I used the value $this->id_nomer based on your code. Where are you getting this value from. Solve this and the code will work for you.